# Querying kafka messages

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a kafka message producer (KafkaProducer) in my spark streaming application.For this I need to detect if a message.value is already exists in the kafka before sending it in my producer

Is there any tool so I can query kafka messages? I don't want to consume message and just querying already existing messages..

Comment: That is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: This is not possible with built-in Kafka functionality.

Maybe you can explain why you need such functionality in your current use case, as there might be other ways to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: I am sending some probe records from a fiestream but records can be repetitive (in the original files) so I need to detect duplicate records (as then have already sent by kafka) before sending them..

Comment: Ah, I see.  In that case my short answer is still valid: there's no out-of-the-box functionality in Kafka that you could readily use, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to lookup key before inserting the value, you might need to use Hbase or MongoDB, or more options: Elasticsearch, Cassandra.
Kafka is a data buffer and it's purpose is for decoupling the system.
You should use the technologies on the right way :)